# What is a Halved Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

If a word has a certain property, I call it a Halved Word™.

In each of the short, unrelated sentences below, only one of the choices is a Halved Word™.

The sentences do not affect whether a word is a Halved Word™. Case, font, and letter/word appearance do not matter.

> 1. This (**scene / segment**) is about declination due to aging.
> 2. Deputy Lee's face was (**agrin / smirky**) as he brought people before the court.
> 3. His (**horse / stallion**) watched the man who gave him new shoes.
> 4. The detailed (**icons / thumbnails**) expressed much information in a tiny space.
> 5. My gastroenterologist's beer (**mug / stein**) is shaped like human entrails.
> 6. It's a device to detect tiny earthquakes for the (**metro / subway**) system.
> 7. The child snitched on his brother while his mom drank a (**cappuccino / latte**).
> 8. The (**anchor / host**) interviewed highly successful, aggressive people.
> 9. He would come back later to try the (**fig / pear**) flavored vodka.
> 10. (**Four / Three**) women in highly decorated dresses get in the line.

**What makes a word a Halved Word™?**

<sub>**Bonus**: You will get 100 bonus rep points **for each** of my [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) or [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles for which you have previously gotten the check mark (2 for Deusovi, 1 for Rodolvertice, CodeNewbie, xnor, Sean, glibdud, f", dperry, and commando)</sub>

<sub>*If you enjoyed this puzzle, and if you feel that it is worthy, remember to upvote it.*</sub>

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A Halved Word™ is a word that,

> when doubled and then anagrammed, produces another English word. As f'' pointed out, each sentence contains a reference to the larger word.

Scene

> scenescene -> senescence (declination due to aging)

Agrin

> agrinagrin -> arraigning (brought people before the court)

Horse

> horsehorse -> horseshoer (the man who gave him new shoes)

Icons

> iconsicons -> concisions (much information in a tiny space)

Stein

> steinstein -> intestines (human entrails)

Metro

> metrometro -> tromometer (thanks, f'') (device to detect tiny earthquakes)

Latte

> lattelatte -> tattletale (snitched)

Host

> hosthost -> hotshots (highly successful, aggressive people)

Pear

> pearpear -> reappear (come back later)

Four

> fourfour -> froufrou (women in highly decorated dresses)

Comment: Each sentence also has a reference to the anagrammed word. The one for metro should be "tromometer", a device for detecting small earthquakes.

Comment: Nice job and great thorough answer!